# Disable nodejs express static cache

Tags: node.js, express, caching, etag

I have used express.static() for getting images from folder. In that folder, image is getting uploaded dynamically. After uploaing image to folder I am not able to access that image from browser. I can access image only after reloading node server. Could you please support me to solve this issue without reloading node server. I have disable etag also. My code is

this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./public"),{etag: false}));

Comment: Well `express.static()` doesn't do any caching of the files as best I can tell.  So, I'd suggest looking at a subsequent request in the Chrome debugger's network tab and see if the browser is just caching the file and not even asking the server or if it's asking the server and the server is telling it there's nothing new or if the server is giving it content, but the old content.  That info will tell you where to look to fix the problem.  FYI, by design `express.static()` is means for `static` content, not content that can change at any time.  So, you're bucking the design a bit.

Comment: FYI, if your images are all in one folder by themselves, it would be easy to write your own custom route handler for files in that directory if `express.static()` won't do what you want.